# how to add output as a new column with the file names

Tags: text-processing, paste

How can I add output of each file incrementally in one singel output? I want to do this instead of running paste command on all files together. It is because I have 10k files and each file is 100 GB in size.

file1

```
a       1
b       2
c       3
```

file2

```
a       10
b       20
c       40
```

file3

```
a       0
b       0
c       0
```

Desired output

```
file1   file1   file2   file2   file3   file3
a       1       a       10      a       0
b       2       b       20      b       0
c       3       c       40      c       0
```

I know I can get some thing similar to desired output using `paste -d "\t" file{1..3}` but I want to perform operation one file after another but not all together and importantly I want to keep the file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` command is a good choice if we just need to merge lines of files.

To prepend *header* line with filenames use combination ***awk*** + ***paste***:

```
{ for f in file*; do awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s\t",FILENAME); exit }' "$f"; done; 
echo ""; paste -d"\t" file*; } | column -t
```

The output (for 3 input files):

```
file1  file1  file2  file2  file3  file3
a      1      a      10     a      0
b      2      b      20     b      0
c      3      c      40     c      0
```

---

Details:

- `{ command; command; ...}` - used to combine outputs of multiple commands
- `for f in file*;` - for each file
- `printf("%s\t",FILENAME)` - print filename for each column of respective file
- `exit` - exits immediately after processing the 1st line

Comment: thanks but i get the following error because i have files with 200k rows each rows and I have 10 k files. Error - column: line 95075 is too long, output will be truncated
.

Comment: @user1703276 "10K files" means that you'll get 20K columns (pretty long). Try without `| column -t`

Comment: Is it possible to remove the duplicate columns (odd columns) except the first column? thanks

Comment: @user1703276, you can create a new question for your new condition